# Make div box load at bottom

Tags: css, html, scroll

I'm working with a project where I need to have a scrollable div element display the bottom when the page loads. This means that the user could scroll upward to see the rest of the content. The only way I could think of doing this would be to have the div autoscroll to the bottom on page load. But since load time is important for this project, I'd like to find another solution. Is there any other way to do this, preferably in something like css? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use javascript to get this effect. It's fast, so you won't have to worry about load times:

```
var yourDiv = document.getElementById('yourDivId');  
yourDiv.scrollTop = yourDiv.scrollHeight;
```

There are also numerous ways to implement this using jQuery. Here's a great blog post on the subject:

[jQuery Scroll To](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

Comment: there is no javascript tag

Comment: @Shaddow No, but this is the only solution (at least from my understanding of the question). The use of JS is often implied unless the asker states that it's not in their question

Comment: Simple, but wonderfully functional. Thanks for saving me lots of trolling through MDN and Quirksmode!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand well what you need, but maybe something like that:

```
#bottomDiv{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `javascript` tag so what about hide element until css file is not downloaded (but this work only for 1st time, then will be css file cached)

```
<div id="bottom" style="display: none;"></div>
```

CSS

```
#bottom {
    display: block !important;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```